# How to get Terraform variable input from the Request Body of an API

Tags: node.js, go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can we run a terraform script - but with variables coming in from an API calls Request Body?
For eg: I want to spin up an EC2 instance, but the name of the EC2 instance and all its other configurations come in from the API Request Body?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for accessing external data sources, such as API, you can use [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source):

> The external data source allows an external program implementing a specific protocol (defined below) to act as a data source, **exposing arbitrary data for use elsewhere** in the Terraform configuration.